# nginx proxy_pass to other server to index.html

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxypass

I have two node with corresponding domain names: server1.test.mydovps.net server2.test.mydovps.net. I want to proxy_pass with upstream from server1.test.mydovps.net to server2.test.mydovps.net and see content of /var/www/server2.test.mydovps.net/index.html

The virtualhost configs are:
server1.test.mydovps.net

```
upstream backend {
server server2.test.mydovps.net:80;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name server1.test.mydovps.net www.server1.test.mydovps.net;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/server1.test.mydovps.net_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/server1.test.mydovps.net_error_log;

    location / {
        return 301 https://server1.test.mydovps.net$request_uri;
    }
}

server {

    # SSL server config

    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name server1.test.mydovps.net www.server1.test.mydovps.net;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/server1.test.mydovps.net_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/server1.test.mydovps.net_error_log;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/nginx-selfsigned-privkey.key;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host backend;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

and server2.test.mydovps.net

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name server2.test.mydovps.net www.server2.test.mydovps.net;
    root /var/www/server2.test.mydovps.net;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/server2.test.mydovps.net_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/server2.test.mydovps.net_error_log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Content of /var/www/server2.test.mydovps.net/index.html:

```
<h1> Hello! </h1>
<h3> From  <strong><em> server2 </em></strong> </h3>
<p> This is simple html to show everything is working fine</p>
```

When I reach https://server1.test.mydovps.net I expect to see my index.html page, but I see "Welcome to nginx page", however when I reach http://server2.test.mydovps.net I see my html page. Two servers are reachable from each other.
Could you please point what are possible errors in nginx configs?

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host backend;` or `proxy_set_header Host "backend";`?

Comment: @LexLi, don't know if I missed somthing, but does it make difference? I used 
`proxy_set_header Host backend;` in my config